# Getting InterruptedException to ignore the interrupt

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupted-exception

I'm new to multi threading (both in general and in Java) and just trying to play around with some basic aspects of interrupted exceptions.

When I run the code below, I am getting the following output -

1: Goodbye, World!
1: Hello, World!
2: Goodbye, World!
3: Goodbye, World!
4: Goodbye, World!
5: Goodbye, World!

But I don't understand why thread 1 (the "Hello, World!") thread is stopping, since its Catch clause is empty (which I thought meant it would ignore the `InterruptedException` and just finish the thread).

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but I just don't know what it is.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

---

```
public class GreetingProducer implements Runnable
{
    String greeting;

    public GreetingProducer (String greetingIn)
    {
        greeting = greetingIn;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(i + ": " + greeting);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable r1 = new GreetingProducer("Hello, World!");
        Runnable r2 = new GreetingProducer("Goodbye, World!");
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: As @Jean Logeart said, it still goes out of the thread. For more, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html.

Comment: 1: Goodbye, World!
1: Hello, World!
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
 at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 at MultithreadingExamples.GreetingProducer.run(GreetingProducer.java:27)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2: Goodbye, World!
3: Goodbye, World!
4: Goodbye, World!
5: Goodbye, World!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `catch` clause may be empty, but the `InterruptedException` is being caught and the catch block executed.

No action is executed since the exception is swallowed, but then the code exits the `try - catch` block as for any other exception.

If you had instructions in the `catch` block, it will be executed.

---

If you want to sleep without interruption, you can use Guava's [sleepUninterruptibly](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Uninterruptibles.html#sleepUninterruptibly(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + ": " + greeting);
    Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Then the `try - catch` block becomes unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, Jean. I know it's a bad idea to ignore interrupt requests, but just for my own edification, how would I go about doing that then? I.e., how do I get the run() method to basically say "yes, I heard your interrupt request, but I'm going to finish everything up anyway."